# UWP Cortana - How to access methods in MyClass.xaml.cs?

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, cortana

I am using Cortana for my UWP app and it works fine.
But when I try to call methods which are not in the app.xaml.cs I fail.

What I am trying to do:

```
// Switch the content of my Frame (works so far)
Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
MainPage page = rootFrame.Content as MainPage;
// cframe references my XAML Frame in the MainPage
page.cframe.Navigate(typeof(MyClass));
// Now the content of the frame is changed and I want to call a method from
// MyClass.xaml.cs
MyClass p = rootFrame.Content as MyClass;
// Here I get a System.NullReferenceException when I try to call
// the "callWebservice()" method from MyClass.xaml.cs
p.callWebservice();
```

How can I access?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by myself:

```
Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
MainPage page = rootFrame.Content as MainPage;
page.cframe.Navigate(typeof(MyClass));
//the next line do the trick
MyClass p = page.cframe.Content as MyClass;
p.callWebservice();
```